# Android force closes on imageview

Tags: android

In folder res/drawable/ I have stored my image pic.jpg, but the application force closes when I run it on my device. The android project was automatically generated, except I have changed the RelativeLayout that encloses everything to a LinearLayout. Inside of this LinearLayout I have only coded a single ImageView. The application force closes without displaying anything. Please, what am I doing wrong?

Relevant XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:src="@+drawable/pic"
    android:contentDescription="@string/none" 
/>
```

Here is the logcat:

```
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imageshow/com.example.imageshow.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class   android.widget.ImageView
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:215)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1679)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at com.example.imageshow.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    ... 11 more
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    ... 22 more
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f020001}
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1907)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:653)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
03-13 12:56:54.920: E/AndroidRuntime(21033):    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:src="@+drawable/pic"
```

should be without a `+` sign. Accessing `/res/drawable` resources is constant - they can't be dynamically generated so having a `+` shouldn't work.

```
android:src="@drawable/pic"
```

Also make sure that your `pic` picture file is *copied* **into** the drawable folder. Linking from the filesystem is not the same since the file is not *actually* in the folder. Linking will result in a *`no resource found that matches the given name`* error.

Comment: I originally tried with your suggestion but eclipse said it was an error and would not build it for me. It says "no resource found that matches the given name". I have pic.jpg in res/drawable so this is confusing to me. I hope this sheds light on what the problem might be though

Comment: Follow <A--C>'s suggestion and then Clean and build your project and then run it.

Comment: @Ameer Moaaviah After cleaning, I get same error, plus "R cannot be resolved to a variable" and it will not let me build...

Comment: @user1951745 Refreshing the project wouldn't hurt either (right click on project ->refresh) if you're on eclipse. Also make sure that your layout files have no errors (red underlines)

Comment: @A--C refreshing the project sadly does not change a thing... Also, Ameer, yes android does include java classes such as the R class which should be generated but apparently I don't have one...

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with how I added the image file? (Right-click drawable->New->File->Advanced->link to existing file on computer - this is the way to do it right?)

Comment: @user1951745 It has to be ***copied*** into your `drawable` folder. I just drag and drop and when prompted click "copy"

Comment: Ah okay. I copied it into the folder, which removed all the errors, but the application still force-closes and does not display anything :/

Comment: @user1951745 clean again, and if it still crashes, update your question with the new LogCat and new XML

Comment: Ah, it's an out-of-memory error so I know what to deal with now. You answered my question (I had to copy the file over, not just link it.) Maybe post that as an answer?

Comment: @user1951745 Edited my existing answer since this is an extension.